# Key Error When Trying to Activate Python Environment

Tags: python, conda, keyerror, virtual-environment

I created a virtual environment with Python using conda. I created it in a folder I called "Test Env" contained in a Python Projects folder in my Documents folder. I get the following error and I have looked everywhere but can't seem to find anyone with my same problem.

I created the environment "conda create --prefix ./'Test Env' "

```
    Fernandos-MBP:Test Env fvarela$ conda activate '/Users/fvarela/Documents/Python Projects/Virtual Environments/Test Env/test'

    # >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 140, in main
        return activator_main()
      File "/Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 1210, in main
        print(activator.execute(), end='')
      File "/Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 178, in execute
        return getattr(self, self.command)()
      File "/Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 152, in activate
        builder_result = self.build_activate(self.env_name_or_prefix)
      File "/Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 300, in build_activate
        return self._build_activate_stack(env_name_or_prefix, False)
      File "/Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 326, in _build_activate_stack
        conda_prompt_modifier = self._prompt_modifier(prefix, conda_default_env)
      File "/Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 695, in _prompt_modifier
        name=basename(prefix),
    KeyError: 'Test Env'

`$ /Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.posix activate /Users/fvarela/Documents/Python Projects/Virtual Environments/Test Env/test`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
                CONDA_EXE=/Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=0
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                     PATH=/Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/bin:/Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/bin:/U
                          sers/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/bin:/Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/bin:/Use
                          rs/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/bin:/Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/condabin:/
                          Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Users/fvarela/.r
                          benv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sha
                          re/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framew
                          ork/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin
                          Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /Users/fvarela/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/fvarela/.condarc
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.6.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.16=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/fvarela/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/fvarela/opt/miniconda3/envs
                          /Users/fvarela/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.7.6 Darwin/20.3.0 OSX/10.16
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

n

No report sent. To permanently opt-out, use

    $ conda config --set report_errors false
```

Comment: I haven't used conda before, but try removing the white spaces in the directory names. So instead of `Test Env` try `test_env` or something similar

Comment: @OliverRobie I tried that but still get the same key error with the same "Test Env" even though the directory is now called "test_env" and I created a new environment named 'testenv'

Comment: Did you change all the directories to not have any spaces in them? Did you delete the original virtual environment you created? Not sure where the `Test Env` would come from without seeing the whole setup. Can you think of where it's coming from?

Comment: This seems like a bug (i.e., [file issue on the Conda repo](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues)). For temporary workaround, try disabling PS1 changes, since that is where the code is erroring out (e.g., `conda config --set changeps1 false`).